# How to restrict website to get opened only from UWP, not from browser

Tags: azure, uwp

I have  a website hosted on azure. The website is expected to get opened only from the UWP application and should be prevented to get open from browser directly. I was checking deep linking `Web-to-App` approach. Are there any other options to do this?

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: @LaurentSchwitter : server? The website is hosted on azure PaaS. Do you mean app service plan?

Comment: What HTTP components is your server application written using?

Comment: @PaulTurner It is an asp.net mvc 5 application.

Comment: Why do you want to restrict access from a web browser? If it is for security reasons then things get tricky. If it is just because the website just doesn't look good, or doesn't work correctly or otherwise is "broken" and you don't want the support cost, then that's a different thing (and much easier to solve).

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT: The UWP application is an OEM kind of application and registration (web app) is just the part of the UWP which opens up from a azure hosted website. So is the business requirement to not allow to access from browser.

Comment: What&#39;s the worst thing that happens if someone opens outside the app? Are there any security concerns?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT : That's the second part of our requirement what-if some hacks. But for now we are looking at if there is anything available to bind the web app to UWP application only something like reverse `appUriHandler` mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do this would be to setup some kind of client authorization mechanism in a way that the app would add some additional request headers to with authentication information that the server would check to verify that the client is indeed the app.

You should look into [**IdentityServer4** documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html), as they show how such functionality can be implemented. You could implement this yourself or use IdentityServer4 or some other tool in the respective language you use on your backend.

Comment: If you're distributing a client, it cannot keep a secret. If it cannot keep a secret, there is no mechanism that can be used to verify its identity which cannot be used by malicious users to spoof their identity.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it is a solution used by most apps. For example for apps using third party authentication like Facebook - if they use client-side SDK they must include the client secret in the package anyway. It is still a better solution than having no authorization at all :-D .

Comment: If an app includes a client secret, they are Doing It Wrong™. There are OAuth flows designed for scenarios where clients cannot keep secrets. You might as well just include an `App-ID` header which contains the client identity: it is exactly as secure.

Comment: I would love to know more, could you post some info on this?

Comment: I'm happy to go into details in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/166773/oauth-2-0-doing-it-wrong

Comment: I am on phone now only, but I will be glad to join later when I get to my PC. However, I think the answer would interest the OP as well, so why not post it as answer to this question :-) ? I will be glad to upvote it as well :-) .